# Reciprocal seems broken... 1/y == y (but y is well defined and not 1)

Tags: python, pandas

Perhaps its just late in the day, and I'm having a brain fart, but...

- if y>0 and y<1
- y is well defined (not NAN or undefined)

then shouldn't 1/y be >1?

I'm seeing 1/y == y. (Taking the reciprocal is a no-op).

```
# rr is a Series of dtype=float64
rr = rr.replace(np.inf, np.nan)
rr = rr.replace(-np.inf, np.nan)
rr = rr.replace(0, 999.9)
print rr.sum()
y = rr[(rr>0) & (rr<1)].copy() # include only those values >0, <1
print "A"
print y.tail()
print "B"
print (1./y).tail()
for i in y:
    assert i>=0 and i<=1
for i in y:
    i = 1/i
    assert i>=1    
for i in (1./y):  # Seems like this look should be the same as the former.
    print i, "GONNA FAIL"
    assert i>=1

2125514.43816 #  rr.sum()  is well defined

A #  y.tail()
0
229994    0.893194
229996    0.997238
229999    0.725193
230000    0.980193
230002    0.819778
Name: rr, dtype: float64

B #  1/y.tail()  ALL THE SAME??!
0
229994    0.893194
229996    0.997238
229999    0.725193
230000    0.980193
230002    0.819778
Name: rr, dtype: float64
0.566025929312 GONNA FAIL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 22, in <module>
AssertionError
```

... so something about pandas' 1/Series looks a little funky.

Results are the same with [`y.rtruediv(1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.truediv.html#pandas.Series.truediv).

Update: Link to the CSV file:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
import requests
url="https://www.dropbox.com/s/2t03ia7vp1vfx0z/rr.csv?dl=1#"
s=requests.get(url).content
rr=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
rr = rr[rr.columns[-1]].rename('rr')

print pd.__version__  # 0.19.2
print np.__version__  # 1.13.0
```

Here's a link to the [full code as a jupyter notebook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2pilewuek6imtji/reciprocalFail.ipynb?dl=1).

Update: More [logs and code in this folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5szx70yunn7k6ok/AAAXVjCI2mQ2Fn5SJ4BjPDjqa?dl=0).

Comment: What version of pandas (and Python) are you using? I did `rr = pd.read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/2t03ia7vp1vfx0z/rr.csv?dl=1#", names = ['index','rr']).rr` and ran everything from the `replace` line onwards, and it worked fine.

Comment: Are you sure you did not print `1./y.tail()` instead of `(1./y).tail()`?

Comment: @Kartik That wouldn't matter because `y` only contains values in (0,1) by construction, so all entries of `1/y` are larger than 1.

Comment: Hi Ken. Is pandas=0.19.2 , numpy=1.13.0. I think the reason you couldn't reproduce it was because I had a bug in the data loader.  rr[rr.columns[1]].rename('rr') should have been rr[rr.columns[-1]].rename('rr')

Comment: "I had a bug" -> So is your question still valid?

Comment: Yes --- still finding that y == 1./y

Comment: I've added a jupyter notebook with the code.

Comment: I ran the code in your Jupyter Notebook unmodified and the assertion didn't fail. All the reciprocals are greater than 1. There doesn't seem to be a problem on pandas 0.20.3 and numpy 1.12.1

Comment: Yup. Is fixed with sudo pip install numpy pandas --upgrade. Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know what the scope of this bug was? I have a *lot* of code that does division.  :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a bug in pandas!

@RyanStout points out that this is fixed in pandas=0.20.3, numpy=1.12.1. Upgrading the libraries fixes it for me also.